# setting states in mapped elements react

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a problem setting the states of other mapped elements to false when clicking on one of the individual mapped element. For example,

```
const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false)
const array = ['witch-king', 'sauron', 'azog']
const arrayrow = array && array.map(el=>{
 return <div>
   <i 
     className='fal fa-edit'
     onClick={(e)=>{
       setEdit(true);
       e.stopPropagation()
     }
   ></i>
   {edit?<i className='fal fa-times'></i>:''}
   <span>{el}</span>
  </div>
})
useEffect(()=>{
document.addEventListener('click', ()=>{setEdit(false)})
},[])
```

The issue is that when you click on one of the icons it will set the state to true, but then if you click on another element's icon, the previously clicked element's state will remain true. I want to be able to set the previously clicked element's state to false when the user clicks on another element's icon.
EDIT: here is a video further explaining what I mean
https://gyazo.com/d8123c9f9a5fcfc48b2149c7faf48bad

Comment: Do you want to toggle state of individual elements on click?

Comment: Ill post a video on my edited question to further explain

Comment: Share the full context of your code.  Where is the value `edit` being used?

Comment: In each element, ill update the code

Comment: Ok see my solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this, but I am not sure if this wont cause current icon to close down.

```js
const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false)
const array = ['witch-king', 'sauron', 'azog']
const arrayrow = array && array.map(el=>{
 return <div>
   <i 
     className='fal fa-edit'
     onClick={(e)=>{
       setEdit(true);
       e.stopPropagation()
     }
   ></i>
   <span>{el}</span>
  </div>
})
useEffect(()=>{
if(edit){
setEdit(false)
}
},[edit])
```

Or try something like

```js
const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false)
const array = ['witch-king', 'sauron', 'azog']

const arrayrow = array && array.map(el=>{
const checkEl = (e, currentEl) => {
if(el === currentEl){
e.stopPropagation()
setEdit(true)
}else{
setEdit(false)
}
}
 return <div>
   <i 
     className='fal fa-edit'
     onClick={(e) => checkEl(e, el)}
   ></i>
   <span>{el}</span>
  </div>
})
useEffect(()=>{
document.addEventListener('click', ()=>{setEdit(false)})
},[])
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

**FULL CODE SOLUTION**

```js
const  MainComponent = () => {
  const [currentEdit, setCurrentEdit] = useState('')
  const array = ['witch-king', 'sauron', 'azog']

  const arrayrow = array && array.map(el=>(
    <ChildComponent 
      key={el} 
      el={el}
      currentEdit={currentEdit}
      handleClick={setCurrentEdit}>
    )
  )

  return (<> {arrayrow} Some JSX </>)
}


const ChildComponent = ({ el, handleClick, currentEdit }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <i 
        className={`fal ${(currentEdit === el) ? 'fa-times' : 'fa-edit' }`}  
        onClick={(e) => {
          handleClick(el)
        }
      ></i>
      <span>{el}</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

Instead of using a boolean, I used the value of each item to represent the currently edited item, and initially, it is set to an empty string like this

```js
const [currentEdit, setCurrentEdit] = useState('')
```

I made a child component passing each the `currentEdit` and the `setCurrentEdit` as props.

```js
<ChildComponent 
  key={el} 
  el={el}
  currentEdit={currentEdit}
  handleClick={setCurrentEdit}> 
)
```

Then do a check inside the child component and reset the `currentEdit` to that element on click

```html
<i 
 className={`fal ${(currentEdit === el) ? 'fa-times' : 'fa-edit' }`}  
 onClick={(e) => {
    handleClick(el)
 }
></i>
```

PS: Remove the `useEffect` with the event listener, adding event listeners like that is an anti-pattern in React, and also you don't need it with this solution.